# do not insert into child table use id if record exists in entity framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have Registration and Department Table.

```
Registration Table:

     public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Username { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> DepartmentID { get; set; }
     public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

Department Table:
  public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
```

I am trying to insert into Registration table and to child table department. But duplicates are getting inserted. I want ID in department table to be inserted into registration if department name already exists.

```
Registration regEntity = new Registration();
            regEntity.ID = reg.ID;
           regEntity.Username = reg.Username;
           regEntity.Email = reg.Email;
          regEntity.Department = new Department { Name = reg.Department };



 WorkOrderDBEntities db = new WorkOrderDBEntities();
                db.Registration.Add(registration);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: By default EF won't insert a duplicate if a record exists. `Exists` means there's another row with the same primary key values. In fact, the *database* itself would refuse to insert a row with the same primary key. Post your actual code, classes, context configuration and table schema. It sounds like the database tables don't even have a primary key

Comment: Its not primary key.Its the duplicate name in department table getting inserted

Comment: Then make it. How else is EF going to know which object is which? Or write a query that checks for existend and then updates. The problem with that is that it will take twice the time and won't always work, because nothing prevents another thread/process/client from modifying the records

Comment: In any case you need to post the relevant information. The classes, table schema, context configuration and make it *clear* that you want to use another field combination as keys instead of the  ... keys. And explain **why** you want to do this - perhaps you don't. Btw if you know a certain field combination is unique, add a unique constraint, either in the database or in the context configuration

Answer (score 0):

You need to get Department ID if it exists in DB, if it does not exist in the DB, you need to first enter the Department entity in the database, then reference it as you are doing.

Comment: Yes.. But if there are many references in one tables gettings the id for each reference makes a call to db each time, which will reduce the performance if the table has tons of records. Is there any easy way without making a call to db each time?

Comment: I think not, because if you need to insert two records into DB it is necessary for you to do two transactions, first to get ID that will be related to the next entity. I am a layman still, but I always do this way.